# If I bounce a 192kHZ file within my DAW while its operating at 44.1kHZ do I loose that quality when I export?

Tags: 192khz

I just realized something while working with some new audio files.

I have been cleaning my audio files which are 24 bit 192kHz in RX then opening them in my DAW -Studio One, making edits, and then exporting them at 192kHZ.

But sometimes I'll perform an edit in Studio One and bounce it internally, and my sessions are running at 44.1kHZ, then export it when I am done at 192kHZ. But if I make edits running in a 44.1kHZ session don't I loose all the the quality I had in the first place?

This isn't meant to be a debate about which rate is the best or necessary. I am just trying my hand at making my first sfx pack for sale and I would like to deliver it in the quality that is preferred.

Is there a way to deal with this. I am using Studio One because I find the I work fast while using it. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you import a 192 kHz audio file in a 44.1 kHz session, the imported audio file will be downsampled. You actually loose information. Exporting this 44.1 kHz session at 192 kHz will use an oversampling algorithm to recreate missing samples.

So you actually loose information, if that's what you mean by quality, when going through this workflow. Is it really audible is an other question.

To deal with this would require using a 192 kHz session in your DAW. I don't know if Studio One offers this possibility.

Comment: Ok everyone. Loose is the opposite of tight and it's an adjective. Lose is the opposite of gain and it's a verb.

Comment: It depends on the DAW whether this is really true. In Reaper for instance, the session's sample rate (from the project settings) is basically only a _preferred setting_. It can be both overridden if the hardware doesn't support the desired rate, and at bouncing (you can choose whether to render at project sampling rate, or at the output format rate).